# Embedded jetty: server stop on application shutdown

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded-jetty in my java application. Is there a way to ensure that the server stops when my application processing is completed. Right now I can only stop the server if I send an interrupt(Ctrl +c) or by explicitly calling server.stop(). Can I circumvent this and make jetty stop.

This is a high level sequence of what I'm doing.

[MAIN THREAD]

- spawns [JETTY-THREAD]

  - REST endpoint of some results computed by APP-THREAD(s)
- spawns [APP-THREAD(s)] (app thread doesn't know jetty is running)

  - Does some processing , writes into some shared object used by JETTY-THREAD
- Waits for APP-THREAD(s) to complete processing; then ends. How do I stop jetty here without invoking server.stop().

Right now I'm not able to get out of my application since jetty is still running.

Comment: Starting the server as a separate Java Thread as a daemon solved the problem.